# Can't access GPU after doing a suspend

Tags: linux, graphics-card, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card

Every time I suspend my laptop, I am unable to do optirun/primusrun because it can't activate the gpu.

```
[ 8597.514526] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 8597.515142] [INFO]Configured driver: nvidia
[ 8597.515421] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[ 8597.515456] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[ 8597.515474] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[ 8597.515496] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[ 8597.515506] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia:/usr/lib32/nvidia
[ 8597.515517] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[ 8597.515527] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[ 8597.515536] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[ 8597.515546] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options:
[ 8597.515555] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/primus:/usr/lib32/primus
[ 8597.515639] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge virtualgl
[ 8597.575176] [INFO]Response: No - error: XORG NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0. Please

[ 8597.575194] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: XORG NVIDIA(0): Failed to initialize the NVIDIA GPU at PCI:1:0:0. Please

[ 8597.575202] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[ 8597.575217] [WARN]The Bumblebee server was not available.
```

I tried some quirks with pm-suspend but nothing really worked. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same happened to my laptop today after upgrading the kernel. Debian & bumblebee.

In my case the module `bbswitch` was missing, so I used `dkms` to build it for the actual kernel version.

- Check kernel version:
  uname -a  (3.12.9, for example)
- Install bbswitch ready for dkms:
  sudo apt-get install dkms-bbswitch (0.8 version, for example)

  (I don't know if kernel-headers is required. Install if necessary)
- Build/install bbswitch:
  sudo dkms install -v 0.8 bbswitch -k 3.12.9
- Restart bumblebeed if necessary:
  sudo service bumblebeed restart